# Is $x^2+25x+4 \in \mathcal{O}(x^2)$? If yes how? If no why not?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Is $x^2+25x+4 \in \mathcal{O}(x^2)$  ? if yes how ?, if no why?

I know $x^2+25x+4\leq 25x^2+25x+25\leq 25x^2+25x^2+25x^2=75x^2$ for some  $x$.

What confuses me is $x^2+25x+4\leq 25x^3+25x+25\leq 25x^3+25x^3+25x^3=75x^3$ for some $x$.

Why is the expression  $O(x^2)$? Why is it not $O(x^3)$?

Comment: Please help us help you.

Comment: What do you know about the $O(\cdot)$ notation? Can you write down the definition you have, and see if it can apply here?

Comment: @ClementC. what about your definition of O(.)? is it or not?

Comment: $f(x)=O(g(x))$ around a point $a\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ if there exists a constant $\alpha > 0$ such that on a neighborhood $V$ of $a$, $f(x)\leq \alpha g(x)$ for all $x\in V$.
Please, specify what is $a$ in your question (usually, either $0$ or $\infty$). Then, tell us what you tried. You must have tried *something*.

Comment: @ClementC. the constant for me is the evil part . whenever i think about the evaluation of function using some value of x. like i give a value to x that after evaluation is lesser than the second term (i.e 25x in this case) in the expression and  it sometimes is more than the term with the highest degree.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The question is: *where* are you looking for an asymptotic? Is it when $x\to\infty$? (then, the answer is "yes") when $x\to 0$ (then, the answer is "no")? when $x\to 7778777$?

Comment: I wanted to vote to reopen, but your last two lines are condescending enough for me to overcome this feeling.

Comment: The key is to understand how to get a least upper bound rather than just selecting an upper bound as instead of using polynomials, you could use exponential functions but how useful is that would be the piece I suspect you are missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way (denoting your expression $f(x)$): for some $x$ (which?)
$$
f(x) \leq 75 x^2 = O(x^2)
$$

EDIT: clearly $x^2 +25 x + 4 \leq 25 x^2 + 25 x + 25   \leq 25 x^2 + 25 x^2 + 25 x^2 = 75 x^2 \ \text{for}  \textit{ some } \ x$

Comment: "just for the record" :-) It is not enough, for example the happens for $x\ln{x}$.

Comment: @Alex can you please elaborate your answer / solution in non mathematical way

Comment: Here $g(x) = 75 x^2$, so $0 \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = C$, in this case $C = \frac{1}{75}$. You can find much sharper bounds of course.

Comment: and how is g(x) - 75x^2 ?

Comment: **Set** $g$ to be the function $g\colon x\mapsto 75x^2$. It is a *choice*. Then $f(x)/g(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{75}$, *so* there exists $A>0$ such that for all $x\geq A$, $0 \leq f(x)/g(x)\leq \frac{2}{75}$.

Comment: see the edit. As I said, you can find sharper bounds

Comment: please don't get me wrong 
clearly x2+25x+4≤25x3+25x+25≤25x3+25x3+25x3=75x3 for some  x

Comment: this is true as well, but $75 x^3 \notin O(x^2)$

Comment: for the purpose of your problem you need $x^2 \leq 25 x^2, \ 25 x \leq 25 x^2$ and $4 \leq 25 x^2$

Comment: but why do i need to have 75x^3 O(x^2)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You wanted to know why your expression is $O(x^2)$. I showed why. I'm not getting where $75 x^3$ comes from

Comment: @Alex please see the last three comments.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you mean that $x^2+2x+4$ is $\mathcal O(x^2)$ **at infinity** and for  this end it is sufficient to prove that 
$$\frac{x^2+2x+4}{x^2}$$
has a finite limit at infinity which's easy to show.

Comment: in this case even $x^2 +2x +4 \sim x^2$ would be true if I'm not mistaken